# Como sei se um valor é maior ou menor que outro valor numa lista usando recursão?

Tags: lista, recursão, comparação, haskell

Sendo um monstro classificado com o seu nome, ataque e defesa.
("medusa", 2, 5) ou seja (string, int, int).
E recebendo uma lista de monstros, como é que crio uma função que me indica se o monstro que eu quero avaliar é mais fraco que os que estão na lista, usando recursividade?
Exemplo:

```
maisFraco ("medusa", 2, 5) [("Pegasus", 10, 3),("hidra", 3, 6)]. Return true.
maisFraco ("minotauro", 5, 4) [("grifo", 10, 3),("trol", 3, 6)]. Return false
```

penso que tenho que percorrer a lista e ir comparando os valores de ataque e defesa, penso que seja usando o map, e depois vou comparando até ambos os valores de ataque e defesa serem maiores que algum na lista, logo aí posso parar a minha função pois o monstro não é o mais fraco (condição de paragem). Mas não sei como agarrar no ataque e na defesa e ir comparando na lista de forma recursiva.

```
maisFraco :: (String, Int, Int) -> [(String, Int, Int)] -> Bool
maisFraco =  

maisFracoAux :: int -> int -> Bool
maisFracoAux x y= if x > y then true else false
```

tentei com uma função auxiliar que compara dois valores para saber se são maiores, mas fico sempre com o problema de ter que comparar dois números

Answer (score 4):

Pra facilitar a sua vida seria melhor criar um tipo que represente um `Monstro`.

Assim, eu criei o seguinte tipo:

```
data Monstro = Status String Int Int
    deriving(Eq, Show) --Obrigatório
```

Para a função você pode usar **guardas**, dessa forma você vai comparando cada elemento da lista com o elemento que deseja verificar se é o `maisFraco` e conforme ele for passando você faz a comparação com o restante da lista. Isso pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
maisFraco :: Monstro -> [Monstro] -> Bool
maisFraco _ [] = True
maisFraco (Status nome f d) ((Status nl fl dl):xs)
    | f < fl && d < dl = maisFraco (Status nome f d) xs
    | otherwise = False
```

No momento que o `Monstro` que se deseja comparar for mais forte em algum aspecto (força ou defesa) ele já retorna `False`. Caso toda lista tenha sido percorrida e a entrada foi uma lista vazia quer dizer que é o `Monstro` mais fraco e retorna `True`.

Answer (score 2):

Já agora um outra versão (esta não recursiva).

```
Considerarei que o monstro M1 é mais fraco que todos  sse 
   não há nenhum M2 tal que 
        M1 possa atacar M2  -- M1.ataque > M2.defesa
        ou 
        M1 consiga defender de M2 -- M1.defesa > M2.ataque
```

O que em Haskell ficaria:

```
mf (_,a,b) ms = not ( any maisfraco ms )
   where maisfraco (_,a1,b1) = a > b1 || b > a1
```

Nota: segundo esta definição os exemplos seriam ambos falsos.